# docker-compose does not update /etc/hosts at build time

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When building an image of a docker container I need to access a service on host localhost.

It looks like `--add-host` option for `docker` command updates `/etc/hosts` both at image build time and container runtime.

The analogous option for `docker-compose` command, `extra_hosts` seems to work only at container runtime. How do I enable it at docker image build time?

Looks like there feature request for that: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7323, but not implemented yet. What would be workaround until this is solved?

## Minimal working example

Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
RUN grep "host.docker.internal" /etc/hosts || echo "Missing"
CMD grep "host.docker.internal" /etc/hosts || echo "Missing"
```

and `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  test:
    build: .
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Running docker:

```bash
docker build . --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway  --no-cache -t test \
    && docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway test
```

prints:

```
172.17.0.1      host.docker.internal
...
172.17.0.1      host.docker.internal
...
```

while:

```bash
docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up
```

returns

```
Missing
...
test_1  | 172.17.0.1    host.docker.internal
...
```

## Motivation

I have a Flask app that depends on my private Python package that I install during docker image build. I store my private Python packages in my local [devpi](https://github.com/devpi/devpi) instance hosted on the same machine I use for building docker image. Hence, my Flask app `pyproject.toml` points to the devpi instance:

```
url = "http://localhost:3141/testuser/dev/+simple"
```

or rather

```
url = "http://host.docker.internal:3141/testuser/dev/+simple"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use [Compose V2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/) and then:

```bash
docker compose build --no-cache && docker compose up
```

(note dashes replaced with spaces).

Here's [specific line](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/v2/pkg/compose/build.go#L259) in implementation.